# How to reference and pass variables to DLL library

Tags: vb.net, dll

Can someone help me with the correct way of doing this. Lets say we have a module that can be used in multiple apps.

```
Public Function releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Function
```

I assume instead of typing it in every app I can create a dll and reference it every time. What would be the procedure for this?

- create a class library in VS
- add the following code:

  ```
  Public Class releaseObject
  ''' <summary>
  ''' releasing objects
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <param name="obj">Object</param>
  Public Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
      Try
          System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
          obj = Nothing
      Catch ex As Exception
          obj = Nothing
      Finally
          GC.Collect()
      End Try
  End Sub
  ```

  End Class
- build and reference dll in the future apps? What is the proper way of using it in the code? I guess how do I pass parameter to the dll?

So in my case I saved dll as a_releaseVars. After I added reference to another app I can see

```
a_releaseVars.releaseObject
```

But once I pass object

```
a_releaseVars.releaseObject(obj)
```

its says that it is a class type and can`t be used as an expression.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Alex

Comment: Are you sure you want your method to get the object `ByVal`? Shouldn't be `ByRef`?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example:
**Library** named ClassLibrary1

```
Public Class RelObject
    Public Sub ReleaseObj(ByRef obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw new Exception(e.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Programm**

```
Imports ClassLibrary1

Public Class Form1
    Dim tb As New Object
    Dim at As New RelObject
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        at.ReleaseObj(tb)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You should take a look at ByVal & ByRef uses and look at your Try Catch Block, which dont make a lot of sense to me. I also can discuss calling GC.Collect there, you are forcing a GC.Collect there, which may not be needed. Garbage Collector is a huge thema and it is worth to take a few reads about how it works and when do we need to interact with it.
At your example you are using the class and not the method of the class, that´s why you are getting the error

Comment: Thank you Rafa. Seems like it works. The code was picked randomly just  as a sample.

Comment: Great! Nice that it works, then you can make my answer as good:) & just for you to know in pluralsight you have very good courses about this topics